# using th:data to fill in the conditional of a th:switch case

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have multiple tables with plus sign links. I want to track which table's link is clicked using customized attributes like th:data-, so that I can create a switch case for information in a modal, based on which link was clicked.

So each table's plus sign link will look like this but with a different data-btnName value.

```html
<th th:if="${role.isCarrierAdmin}" class="text-right"><a  th:data-btnName="Commercial" class="trigger-add-contact btn btn-default" id="addCommercialContact" name="addCommercialContact"><span class="fa fa-plus"></span></a></th>
```

I am not sure how to grab the link data-attribute for the switch case... could someone please advise?

would it be something like this?

```html
<div th:switch="${data-btnName}=='Commercial'">
    <div th:case="true" class="row"> show this code here </div>
    <div th:case="false" class="row"> or show this code here </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Just a guess: switch on `data-btnName` with case values as `Commercial`, etc.

Comment: Sorry, I think I was unclear. I need to know how to grab/write the custom attribute inside the switch case. <div th:switch="{What goes here?? }=='Commercial'">

Comment: You can't parse values that already exist in HTML.